# F# recursive function arguments and stack overflow

Tags: recursion, f#

I am somewhat new to F#, and I came across some strange behaviour when I was working with some recursive functions.  I have two different versions of it below:

Version 1:
This causes a stack overflow, though it seems that it shouldn't (at least to my noob eyes)

```
let rec iMake acc =
  match acc with
  | 10 -> 100
  | _ -> iMake acc+1
```

Version2:
This one works as I would expect it to.

```
let rec iMake acc =
  match acc with
  | 10 -> 100
  | _ -> iMake (acc+1)
```

The only difference is that version 2 puts the acc+1 expression into parenthesis.  So my question is, why does the first version not work, but the second one does?  Does this mean that I should put all of my function arguments into parenthesis to avoid this type of stuff in the future ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Function call` has higher precedence than binary operator `+`. So the first function actually works like:

```
let rec iMake acc =
    match acc with
    | 10 -> 100
    | _ -> (iMake acc)+1
```

Comment: I see, so it is trying to add one to the result of (iMake acc), and that is where the stackoverflow is coming from.  acc is effectively never incremeted, interesting.